# RTSP streaming doesn't work

Tags: android, media-player

I've created an app which will play from on RTSP:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

try 
{
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(
        "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov");
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(MyYouTubeActivity.this, 
        "Eror Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}           

mediaPlayer.start();
```

But it's not working, in Logcat I see this:

```
09-12 12:57:20.899: ERROR/PlayerDriver(95): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
```

Answer (score 0):

**First inset permission ::**

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.INTERNET
```

**code ::**

```
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource("url");
            player.prepare();
                        player.start();
```

and also refer  :: [**This**](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c5e6135e6f9a242c)

Comment: you need to start Internet in your device and then execute

Comment: Start already :(, I can view video from youtube YouTube app of android but my app is not!

Comment: try to put music in local folder

Comment: What do you mean, my question is the problem with RTSP :-<

Comment: please try first locally and then get data from server

Comment: With the local my app work good but with the rtsp below it's not work :(

Comment: try to http//184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov

Comment: make sure "mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k" name of audio is correct or directory is correct?

Comment: Like I said, It's work with 3G but when I use wifi at my home it's not work and then I've go to my school and use wifi there ==> it's work! Too difficult to understand what wrong :(

Comment: try to convert `mov` file to `3gp`. but i think this is big issue related n/w. like 3g give full bandwidth to download video and school wifi also enable with huge bandwidth but may be your home bandwidth are lower so it will raise this problem.   +1

Comment: I've try 3gp with youtube API also but it' not work again. I think the problem come from the UDP paket of RTSP :-?

Comment: no youtube video display process is little differant from natural step but i think we maximum concentrate with server

Comment: just try with TCP and tell me problem

Comment: Oh thank, I'll try with these link , thanks again and will feedback soon!

Comment: Not work, It's seem the firewall of android don't accept the rtsp stream, I think so because when I test rtsp with VLC on windows, the FireWall ask me to accept that connection :) Any idea?

Comment: try with http connection,simply whenever i want to load media resource from server i have always get from http

Comment: make sure your computer setting are completely gone good. and also check wifi setting.

Comment: Ofcourse, I can read news by Operamini with wifi but stream with rtsp it's not work (just rtsp), your link is the mov type of video and ofcourse it working :(